# React Material UI can't find mobile device on first render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive

I'm using `material ui` in my `REACT` `pwa`.
When i try to open the application in mobile device screen size won't detect at initialization. So my tree will render twice and i see screen blinking with on-the-fly responsive changes.

```js
import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));

    const render=useRef(0);

    console.log(++render.current);
    console.log('material answering to is mobile:',isMobile)

    return (
        <div/>
    )
}
```

[image]

Is there something i don't know about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[according to the doc](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#usemediaquery-query-options-matches), MediaQueries accept two arguments:

```
useMediaQuery(query, [options]) => matches
```

and one of its options is noSsr which is:

> options.noSsr (Boolean [optional]): Defaults to false. In order to
> perform the server-side rendering reconciliation, it needs to render
> twice. A first time with nothing and a second time with the children.
> This double pass rendering cycle comes with a drawback. It's slower.
> You can set this flag to true if you are not doing server-side
> rendering.

As a result, if you want to prevent this behaviour, set it to true as below:

```
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"), {
    noSsr: true
  });
```

[working example in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-lyki9?file=/demo.js:156-240)